# trying to find element of array from which sum of left side of array is equal to sum of right side of array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find element of array from which sum of left side of array is equal to sum of right side of array in JavaScript

**I am using:**

```
function findEvenIndex(arr)
{
  //Code goes here!
    let num = 0;
  
  function check(i){
    console.log(arr);
    console.log(num)
    let arrPart1 = arr.slice(0,i).reduce(((a,b)=>a+b),0);
    console.log(arrPart1)
    let arrPart2 = arr.slice(i+1,arr.length).reduce(((c,d)=>c+d),0);
    console.log(arrPart2)
    
    if(arrPart2 === 0){
      return -1
    }
    else if(arrPart1 !== arrPart2){
      num++;
      check(num);
    }
  }
  return check(num);
}
```

**For array:**

```js
[1,100,50,-51,1,1]
```

**Getting:**

```js
[ 1, 100, 50, -51, 1, 1 ]
0
0
101

[ 1, 100, 50, -51, 1, 1 ]
1
1
1
```

**Error:**

The array was: `[1,100,50,-51,1,1]`

: expected `undefined` to equal 1

Comment: You never `return` anything else but `-1`, so the result is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend abandoning the recursive solution and opting for an iterative one - in this situation, it's easier to debug. I've written a function that is easy to understand and can solve your problem here:

```
function findEvenIndex(arr)
{
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let leftTotal = arr.slice(0, i).reduce((t, v) => t + v, 0);
    let rightTotal = arr.slice(i + 1).reduce((t, v) => t + v, 0);
    if (leftTotal === rightTotal) {
      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem in recursive function? I don't understand the answer is right their, but i am not able to return it.

Comment: The problem in the recursive function is that you are missing a crucial base case. You return -1 when you finish iterating through the array and don't find an "even index", but you don't return the index when you FIND the "even index". You need another base case :
"
else if (arrPart1 === arrPart2) {
      return i;
    }
"
You also need to return the check(num) in the first else-if.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```js
const findElementIndex = (array, index = 0) => {
  let arr_part_1 = array.slice(0, index).reduce(((a, b) => a + b), 0);
  let arr_part_2 = array.slice(index + 1, array.length).reduce(((a, b) => a + b), 0);
  return arr_part_1 === arr_part_2 ? index : index === array.length ? -1 : findElementIndex(array, index + 1);
};

console.log('Example 1: ', findElementIndex([1, 1, 10, 2]));
console.log('Example 2: ', findElementIndex([1, 1, 1, 10, 2]));
console.log('Example 3: ', findElementIndex([100, 1, 100]));
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First check if the array length is an even number

   ```
   if (array.length % 2 === 1) {
     return false;
   }
   ```
2. Slice the array in half and reverse the 2nd half

   ```
   let half = (array.length / 2);
   let sub1 = array.slice(0, half);
   let sub2 = array.slice(-half).reverse();
   ```
3. Then filter both and return matches

   ```
   return sub1.filter((num, idx) => num === sub2[idx]);
   ```

```js
const array1 = [1, 100, 50, -51, 1, 1];
const array2 = [5, 62, 8, 0, 0, 15, 62, -5];
const array3 = [0, 1, 0];

const mirroredValues = array => {
  let half;
  if (array.length % 2 === 1) {
    return false;
  } else {
    half = (array.length / 2);
  }
  let sub1 = array.slice(0, half);
  let sub2 = array.slice(-half).reverse();

  return sub1.filter((num, idx) => num === sub2[idx]);
};

console.log(mirroredValues(array1));
console.log(mirroredValues(array2));
console.log(mirroredValues(array3));
```

Answer (score 0):

That one could be better from performance point of view (reduce only once)

```js
function inTheMiddle(arr) {
    let rightSum = arr.slice(2).reduce((total, item) => total + item, 0);
    let leftSum = arr[0];
    console.log(leftSum, rightSum);
    for (let i = 2; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (leftSum === rightSum) {
            return i-1;
        }
        leftSum += arr[i-1];
        rightSum -= arr[i];
        console.log(leftSum, rightSum);
    }
    return -1;
}

console.log("In the middle:", inTheMiddle([1,100,50,-51,1,1]))
```